# Display video from CDN

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm using [video.api](https://api.video/) to host my videos. I'm able to upload videos, the problem i'm facing is how to play those videos on my front end application.
I'm making some tests using only html5 and javascript.
I'm having problems understand the response when i hit the GET video endpoint.

```
{
"videoId": "vi7fwJPdZNoSxKldYjLYrHio",
"title": "Creating test",
"description": "TEST3",
"public": false,
"publishedAt": "2018-09-26T15:56:53+02:00",
"tags": [
    "maths",
    "string theory",
    "video"
],
"metadata": [
    {
        "key": "Author",
        "value": "John Doe"
    },
    {
        "key": "Format",
        "value": "Tutorial"
    }
],
"source": {
    "uri": "/videos/vi7fwJPdZNoSxKldYjLYrHio/source"
},
"assets": {
    "iframe": "<iframe 

    src=\"https://embed.api.video/vod/vi7fwJPdZNoSxKldYjLYrHio? 
    token=c0e981f1-19a5-474d-9f86-542b6b4d3b02\" width=\"100%\" 
     height=\"100%\" frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\" 
     allowfullscreen=\"\"></iframe>",
    "player": "https://embed.api.video/vod/vi7fwJPdZNoSxKldYjLYrHio? 
    token=c0e981f1-19a5-474d-9f86-542b6b4d3b02",
    "hls": 

   "https://cdn.api.video/vod/vi7fwJPdZNoSxKldYjLYrHio/token/c0e981f1- 
    19a5-474d-9f86-542b6b4d3b02/hls/manifest.m3u8",
    "thumbnail": 

   "https://cdn.api.video/vod/vi7fwJPdZNoSxKldYjLYrHio/token/c0e981f1- 
    19a5-474d-9f86-542b6b4d3b02/thumbnail.jpg"
   }
}
```

I think i should one of the links in the `assets` But i don't know which one and how to, any help will be appreciated, i found [this](https://docs.api.video/5.1/vod-tutorial/embed-videos) in the documentation but i dont quite understand it. Thank you

Comment: How about using the iframe?

Comment: I tried it , but no it doesn't work it only shows a video player with a black screen. when inspecting the console i get a impossible to load player JSON config error.

Comment: The item you want to reference in your html5 video source is the hls parameter. Of course, this is only supported in browsers (or player frameworks) which support HLS

Comment: Your m3u8 link doesn't work (if existing, it should play or download as text file) : https://cdn.api.video/vod/vi7fwJPdZNoSxKldYjLYrHio/token/c0e981f1-19a5-474d-9f86-542b6b4d3b02/hls/manifest.m3u8

Comment: Your Jpeg (thumbnail) link doesn't work... : https://cdn.api.video/vod/vi7fwJPdZNoSxKldYjLYrHio/token/c0e981f1-19a5-474d-9f86-542b6b4d3b02/thumbnail.jpg